# Selecting GWT module to compile for deployment to App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, google-eclipse-plugin

I introduced additional GWT modules where previously there's only been one in my GWT/GAE project. When deploying to App Engine via Google Plugin for Eclipse I noticed that the plugin compiles all the GWT modules in the project, which is not what I want. I wasn't able to find a way to tell GPE which GWT modules to compile for deployment. Is this at all possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently GPE compiles GWT modules in the module list found in *Project Properties --> Google --> Web Toolkit* so removing modules from there did the trick. I was expecting to find either a way to select GWT modules from the GAE Deployment Dialog or to edit some configuration file.

It has to be admitted that relying on such GPE settings is not a great way to make consistent deployments. Maven-based builds and deployments made outside of Eclipse are likely a better way to go.